# How to display the number of times something has occured

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server :

```
SELECT tblModule.Title , Count (tblActivity.Name) AS NumberOfActivities 
From tblActivity
INNER JOIN tblModule 
  ON tblModule.ModuleID = tblActivity.ModuleID
  Order by tblModule.Title
```

In here I am trying to display the number of times Name is displayed in tblActivity for each Module Title , How would I do this the error is :

```
 Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tblModule.Title' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

And the actual question : For each module, list the module title and the number of activities scheduled for the module.(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.Title, COUNT_BIG(a.Name) AS NumberOfActivities 
FROM dbo.tblActivity a
JOIN dbo.tblModule m ON m.ModuleID = a.ModuleID
GROUP BY m.Title
ORDER BY m.Title
```

or

```
SELECT m.Title, NumberOfActivities
FROM (
    SELECT ModuleID, COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumberOfActivities 
    FROM dbo.tblActivity
    GROUP BY ModuleID
) a
JOIN dbo.tblModule m ON m.ModuleID = a.ModuleID
ORDER BY m.Title
```

anyway, please provide actual and excepted result...